# How to scrape a web site with sucuri protection

Tags: python, scrapy, cloudflare

According to [Scrapy Documetions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) I want to crawl and scrape data from several sites, My codes works correctly  with usual website,but when I want crawl a website with **Sucuri** I don't get any data, it seems sucuri firewall prevent me to access to websites markups.

The target website is http://www.dwarozh.net/ and 
This is  my spider snippet

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import scrapy

from Stack.items import StackItem
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


    class StackSpider(Spider):
        name = "stack"
        start_urls = [
            "http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/",
        ]


        def parse(self, response):
            mItems = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="news-more-img"]/ul/li')
            for mItem in mItems:
                item = StackItem()
                item['title'] = mItem.xpath(
                    'a/h2/text()').extract_first()
                item['url'] = mItem.xpath(
                    'viewa/@href').extract_first()
                yield item
```

And this is result I get in response

```
<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
<script>var s={},u,c,U,r,i,l=0,a,e=eval,w=String.fromCharCode,sucuri_cloudproxy_js='',S='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';L=S.length;U=0;r='';var A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';for(u=0;u<64;u++){s[A.charAt(u)]=u;}for(i=0;i<L;i++){c=s[S.charAt(i)];U=(U<<6)+c;l+=6;while(l>=8){((a=(U>>>(l-=8))&0xff)||(i<(L-2)))&&(r+=w(a));}}e(r);</script></html>
```

**How can I bypass sucuri with scrapy?**

Comment: you could rewrite JavaScript code to Python and use it to decode encrypted data.

Comment: @furas how? please provide more details and if you can a snippet for your comment

Comment: Simple, get that code inside <script></script> tags and evaluate it. It basically sets a cookie like this *`sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_181de1112=021zf6475f112ez2d96c6fa0f411183f;path=/;max-age=86400`* and reloads the window/tab/page.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. would you please provide more details or helper link about this solution

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. I asked about scraping , there is not windows/tab/page :/

Comment: @zhilevan I'm just telling you what the script does. I just said how to do it.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. thanks for your attention but it's not my answer, it seems you didn't see my description about scrapy !!! if you can help me please provide a answer with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Site uses cookie- and user-agent based protection. You may check it in such a way. Open DevTools in Chrome. Navigate to the target page http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/, then in Network tab right click on the request to the page and "Copy as CURL"
Open console and run the cURL:

```
$ curl 'http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/all-hawal.aspx?cor=3&Nawnishan=%D9%88%DB%95%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%B4%DB%95%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%20%D8%AF%DB%8C%DA%A9%DB%95' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'X-Compress: null' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/details.aspx?jimare=10505' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=dc9867; sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_ce28bca9c=d36ad9; ASP.NET_SessionId=wqdo0v; __atuvc=1%7C49; sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_0d5c=6ab0; _gat=1; __asc=7c0b5; __auc=35; _ga=GA1.2.19688' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

You will see normal html code. If you remove cookie of User-Agent from the request, you get the cap page.

Lets check it in scrapy:

```
$ scrapy shell
>>> from scrapy import Request
>>> cookie_str = '''here; your; cookies; from; browser; go;'''
>>> cookies = dict(pair.split('=') for pair in cookie_str.split('; '))
>>> cookies  # check them
{'__auc': '999', '__cfduid': '796', '_gat': '1', '__atuvc': '1%7C49', 'sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_0d5c97a96': '6ab007eb1
9', 'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'u9', '_ga': 'GA1.2.1968.148', '__asc': 'sfsdf', 'sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_ce2
sfsdfs': 'sdfsdf'}
>>> r = Request(url='http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/', cookies=cookies, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome
/54. Safari/5'})
>>> fetch(r)
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="news-more-img"]/ul/li')
[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="news-more-img"]/ul/li' data='<li><a href="details.aspx?jimare=10507">'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="news-more-img"]/ul/li' data='<li><a href="de
tails.aspx?jimare=10505">'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="news-more-img"]/ul/li' data='<li><a href="details.aspx?jimare=10504">'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="news-more-img"]/
ul/li' data='<li><a href="details.aspx?jimare=10503">'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="news-more-img"]/ul/li' data='<li><a href="details.aspx?jimare=10323">'>]
```

Excellent! Let's make a spider:

I've modified yours because I have no source code of some components.

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import scrapy

#from Stack.items import StackItem
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class StackSpider(Spider):
        name = "dwarozh"
        start_urls = [
            "http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/",
        ]
        _cookie_str = '''__cfduid=dc986; sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_ce=d36a; ASP.NET_SessionId=wq; __atuvc=1%7C49; sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_0d5c97a96=6a; _gat=1; __asc=7c0b; __auc=3; _ga=GA1.2.196.14'''
        _user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54 Safari/5'

        def start_requests(self):
            cookies = dict(pair.split('=') for pair in self._cookie_str.split('; '))
            return [Request(url=url, cookies=cookies, headers={'User-Agent': self._user_agent})
                    for url in self.start_urls]

        def parse(self, response):
            mItems = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="news-more-img"]/ul/li')
            for mItem in mItems:
                item = {} # StackItem()
                item['title'] = mItem.xpath('a/h2/text()').extract_first()
                item['url'] = mItem.xpath('viewa/@href').extract_first()
                yield {'url': item['url'], 'title': item['title']}
```

Lets run it:

```
$ scrapy crawl dwarozh -o - -t csv --loglevel=DEBUG
/Users/el/Projects/scrap_woman/.env/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.log` has been deprecated, Scrapy now relies on the builtin Python library for logging. Read the updated logging entry in the documentation to learn more.
  return f(*args, **kwds)
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.1 started (bot: scrap1)
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrap1.spiders'], 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'BOT_NAME': 'scrap1', 'FEED_URI': 'stdout:', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrap1.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True}
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2016-12-10 00:18:55 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dwarozh.net/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/> (referer: None)
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/>
{'url': None, 'title': '\nلیستی یاریزانانی ریاڵ مەدرید بۆ یاری سبەی ڕاگەیەنراو پێنج یاریزان دورخرانەوە'}
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/>
{'url': None, 'title': '\nهەواڵێکی ناخۆش بۆ هاندەرانی ریاڵ مەدرید'}
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/>
{'url': None, 'title': '\nگرنگترین مانشێتی ئەمرۆ هەینی رۆژنامەکانی ئیسپانیا'}
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/>
{'url': None, 'title': '\nبەفەرمی یۆفا پێكهاتەی نموونەی جەولەی شەشەم و کۆتایی چامپیۆنس لیگی بڵاو کردەوە'}
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/>
{'url': None, 'title': '\nكچە یاریزانێك دەبێتە هۆیی دروست بوونی تیپێكی تۆكمە'}
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] INFO: Stored csv feed (5 items) in: stdout:
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 950,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 15121,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 9, 21, 18, 56, 271371),
 'item_scraped_count': 5,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 9, 21, 18, 55, 869851)}
2016-12-10 00:18:56 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
url,title
,"
لیستی یاریزانانی ریاڵ مەدرید بۆ یاری سبەی ڕاگەیەنراو پێنج یاریزان دورخرانەوە"
,"
هەواڵێکی ناخۆش بۆ هاندەرانی ریاڵ مەدرید"
,"
گرنگترین مانشێتی ئەمرۆ هەینی رۆژنامەکانی ئیسپانیا"
,"
بەفەرمی یۆفا پێكهاتەی نموونەی جەولەی شەشەم و کۆتایی چامپیۆنس لیگی بڵاو کردەوە"
,"
كچە یاریزانێك دەبێتە هۆیی دروست بوونی تیپێكی تۆكمە"
```

Possibly you will have to update cookies from time to time. You may use PhantomJS for this.

**UPDATE**:

How to get cookies using PhantomJS.

1. Install [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html).
2. Make script like this `dwarosh.js`:

   ```
   var page = require('webpage').create();
   page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
   page.open('http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/', function(status) {
     console.log("Status: " + status);
     if(status === "success") {
       page.render('example.png');
       page.evaluate(function() {
       return document.title;
     });
     }
     for (var i=0; i<page.cookies.length; i++) {
       var c = page.cookies[i];
       console.log(c.name, c.value);
     };
     phantom.exit();
   });
   ```
3. Run script:

   ```
     $ phantomjs --cookies-file=cookie.txt dwarosh.js
     TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating  'activeElement.position().left')

     http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/js/script.js:5
     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 in c
     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 in fireWith
     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 in ready
     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 in q
   Status: success
   __auc 250ab0a9158ee9e73eeeac78bba
   __asc 250ab0a9158ee9e73eeeac78bba
   _gat 1
   _ga GA1.2.260482211.1481472111
   ASP.NET_SessionId vs1utb1nyblqkxprxgazh0g2
   sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_3e07984e4 26e4ab3...
   __cfduid d9059962a4c12e0f....1
   ```
4. Get cookie `sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_3e07984e4` and try to get the page with `curl` and the same User-Agent.

   ```
   $ curl -v http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/ -b sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_3e07984e4=26e4ab377efbf766d4be7eff20328465 -A SpecialAgent
   *   Trying 104.25.209.23...
   * Connected to www.dwarozh.net (104.25.209.23) port 80 (#0)
   > GET /sport/ HTTP/1.1
   > Host: www.dwarozh.net
   > User-Agent: SpecialAgent
   > Accept: */*
   > Cookie:     sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_3e07984e4=26e4ab377efbf766d4be7eff20328465
   >
   < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   < Date: Sun, 11 Dec 2016 16:17:04 GMT
   < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   < Connection: keep-alive
   < Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d1646515f5ba28212d4e4ca562e2966311481473024; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-17 16:17:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.dwarozh.net; HttpOnly
   < Cache-Control: private
   < Vary: Accept-Encoding
   < Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=srxyurlfpzxaxn1ufr0dvxc2; path=/; HttpOnly
   < X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
   < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
   < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
   < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   < X-Sucuri-ID: 15008
   < Server: cloudflare-nginx
   < CF-RAY: 30fa3ea1335237b0-ARN
   <
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/><title>
   Dwarozh : Sport
   </title><meta content="دواڕۆژ سپۆرت هەواڵی ناوخۆ،هەواڵی جیهانی، وەرزشەکانی دیکە" name="description"/><meta property="fb:app_id" content="1713056075578566"/><meta content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/><link href="wene/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/><link href="wene/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script src="js/classie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   ```

Comment: I try this in this situation, first open website in chorme, my OS is MAC, then  grab cookies and changes cookie in your strings with `        _cookie_str = ''' sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_328445b41=5996855a2e6fb90c76a6f6c8666626cc; ASP.NET_SessionId=0ihhn0geh01tupszduatzhvq; __cfduid=d44ad0c2103e825786f4a99bbc2d099c51481196678; __asc=31cac9b4158e861268f99516a8b; __auc=d4f610c3158e038467b56753acb; _ga=GA1.2.714700409.1481230534; _gat=1'''
        _user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54 Safari/5'`  but no result :(

Comment: Does cURL return normal html page?

Comment: The site requires 2 cookies: first is installed at first request as httpOnly, also browser receives a chunk of an obfuscated JavaScript code, after decifering and `eval` the code sets another cookie and reloads a page.
Then, having both cookies you may open a page.
`document.cookie
"sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_3be923a3e=da...; sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_0d5c97a96=f43..."`

Comment: Right click, "Copy as CURL", paste into console, add "-v" and run.
Works for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFgG2OYs2E&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Really Thanks for your help, finally I could got it, but some question, what time this cookie will be valid? is there any solution we could get this cookie from python? because I want to write a server spider to crawl and scrape several sites.

Comment: I haven't check cookie lifetime - I think it depends on sucuri and can change suddenly. Anyway program should not rely on it and be ready to obtain fresh cookie.

Comment: Pls take a look, I've updated the recipe, how to get cookie with PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks you very much,  still it need some manual action, how abut splash, there is a library to integrate  scrapy with splash, https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash. do you think it could help me?
I looking for a full automatic solution if it possible.

Comment: Unfortunately can say nothing about it.

Comment: would you pelase write done this command `Get cookie sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_3e07984e4 and try to get the page with curl and the same User-Agent.` ? I didn't see code in step 4.

Comment: when I try to `console.log(page.title)` on phantomjs it's return `You are being redirected...` this is means phantomjs can't treat as a usual browser, it this right?

Comment: You may use grep like `phantomjs .... | grep sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid` - it'll show you only this matchiing string. Then you may run in your mac's terminal `curl -v http://www.dwarozh.net/sport/ -b "sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_3e07984e4=26e4ab3.." -A SpecialAgent`  after `-b` should go real cookie name and value.

Answer (score 3):

The general solution to parse dynamic content will be to first get rendered dom/html by using something able to run Javascript (for example http://phantomjs.org/) then save html and feed it to a parser.

This will also help to bypass some js-based protectors.

`phantomjs` is a single executable file and it will load a uri as a real browser with all JS evaluated.
You can run it from Python by `subprocess.call([phantomJsPath, jsProgramPath, url, htmlFileToSave])`

For jsProgram example you can check https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

To save html from the js program, use `fs.write(htmlFileToSave, page.content, "w");`

I've tested this method on dwarozh.net and it worked, though you should figure out how to plug this into your `scrapy` pipeline.

Specifically for your example, you can try to "manually" parse the provided javascript to get cookie detail which is required to load the actual page. Though Sucuri algorithm may be changed at any moment and any solution based on cookie or js-decoding will became broken.

Comment: Thanks for you attention, I also tried something like you suggested, via https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash  and https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash but not worked for me :(.
can your provide some snippet or scrapy-base solution please?
**Note: I want crawl and scrape several sites hourly** and my method must be fast.