# Cant find element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have the following xpaths:

```
<a class="btn btn-small downloadlink" rel="nofollow" data-
toggle="tooltip" data-format="ico" data-icon-id="1715795" 
href="/icons/1715795/download/ico" data-original-title="Download this 
icon in ICO format for use in Windows."><i class="download-icon"></i><b>
ICO</b></a>

<a class="btn btn-small downloadlink" rel="nofollow" data-
toggle="tooltip" data-format="icns" data-icon-id="1715795" 
href="/icons/1715795/download/icns" data-original-title="Download this 
icon in ICNS format for use in Apple OS X."><i class="download-icon"></i><b>
ICNS</b></a>
```

(from here: https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1715795/earth_planet_space_icon#size=128)

Using selenium, I want to select the element that corresponds to the xpath that contains:

```
data-format="icns"
```

I've tried something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-format="icns"]')
```

but it gives the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such 
element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*
[@data-format=icns]"}
```

**Q:** How can I select the the second element?

I know I can just copy the xpath from inspection, but this would leave me with a very unstable scraping script. Since tiny changes in the page layout could mean that my xpath expression would no longer be valid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean `it doesn't work`?

Comment: Selenium cant find element with that xpath

Comment: Have you tried with css to see if it's the fault of the xpath and not a timing issue? `a[data-format="icns"]`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a timing issue. When I add a time.sleep(4) it still doesn't work. Is driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-format="icns"]') a correct statement though?

Comment: @titusAdam, check whether your element located inside an `iframe`

Comment: Could you check that you have your html in the selenium object? your xpath is right and I obtain the element when I tested it via lxml

Comment: @Andersson nope! (I've added the url to my question).

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov How would I do so?

Comment: @titusAdam, Did try other selectors, like `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href="/icons/1715795/download/icns"]')` , `driver.find_element_by_link_text('ICNS')`..?

Comment: you can get it using 'driver.page_source'

Comment: @titusAdam just a little question, do you want download the ico ?

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov Yes the html is in the selenium object. Andersson driver.find_element_by_link_text('ICNS') does work. It just don't understand why I can't use xpaths. wu4m4n Yes that's what I want.

Comment: @titusAdam perfect! i already post my solution! I

Comment: @wu4m4n I know how to download the icon! I just want to know why the xpath isn't working! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import lxml.html

url = "https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1715795/earth_planet_space_icon#size=128"

#if you use selenium, comment this line.
resp = requests.get(url)

#you can replace this line if you use selenium
#source_code = browser.page_source

source_code = resp.text

root = lxml.html.fromstring(source_code)

id_icon = set(root.xpath('//*[@data-format="icns"]//@data-icon-id'))

#just if you want download all the icons

for id in id_icon:
    url = 'https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/{0}/check-download/icns'.format(id)

    local_filename = '{0}.icns'.format(id)
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

    print "downloaded  {0}".format(local_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to scrap a site and download some object I can recommend use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) - it's much better/faster/more reliable for scraping than selenium.

For example:

```
$ scrapy shell
2017-01-08 23:36:58 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-01-08 23:36:58 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'}
.... debug info ....
2017-01-08 23:36:58 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-01-08 23:36:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x10cfe7cc0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x10cfe7eb8>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

# fetch data and prepare all helpers to work
>>> fetch('https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1715795/earth_planet_space_icon#')

# now object `response` contains result of our request
>>> response
<200 https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1715795/earth_planet_space_icon>

# let's check links:
>>> response.xpath('//*[@data-format="icns"]')
[<Selector xpath='//*[@data-format="icns"]' data='<a class="btn btn-small downloadlink" re'>, <Selector xpath='//*[@data-format="icns"]' data='<a class="btn btn-small downloadlink"
re'>, <Selector xpath='//*[@data-format="icns"]' data='<a class="btn btn-small downloadlink" re'>, <Selector xpath='//*[@data-format="icns"]' data='<a class="btn btn-small downloadl
ink" re'>, ...... ]

# extract first of them
>>> link = response.xpath('//*[@data-format="icns"]')[0]
>>> link.extract()
'<a class="btn btn-small downloadlink" rel="nofollow" title="Download this icon in ICNS format for use in Apple OS X." data-toggle="tooltip" data-format="icns" data-icon-id="1715795
" href="/icons/1715795/download/icns"><i class="download-icon"></i><b>\n    ICNS</b></a>'

# URL of a link
>>> link.select('@href').extract_first()
'/icons/1715795/download/icns'

# add host and other params to form a full URL
>>> response.urljoin(link.select('@href').extract_first())
'https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1715795/download/icns'
```

In fact Scrapy is capable of much-much more. For example, it can recursively find and download all links for you.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I've worked with scrapy! However, I need selenium to download stuff from a website that uses javascript (Not this example)

Comment: Yes, Scrapy doesn't support JS directly. Have you tried [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Scrapy-splash](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/) to prepare pages for the Scrapy?

Comment: No I havent, I will do so! Do you know if there's a package like scrapy for java?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't worked with Java, so I can't recommend something like Scrapy.

Comment: Do you have an example of scraping with scrapy and phantomjs? I don't know how to prepare pages for scrapy.

Comment: I used it to get cookies, but it can also return some other things - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005076/how-to-scrape-a-web-site-with-sucuri-protection/41069273#41069273

Comment: Is it true that Phantomjs isn't compatible with python any longer?

Comment: It seem be yes. You may run it as a standalone application or use Splash.